# pandas - getting max rows from groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
    id  value col1 col2 col3
 0   1   10    W    A    B
 1   1   15    X    Y    Z
 2   2   4     K    L    M
 3   3   8     M    N    B
 4   3   15    M    N    B
```

And following gives the columns with max `value` for each id with `groupby()` and `transform()`

```
df.groupby("id")["value"].transform(max)
```

Output:

```
1   15
2   4
3   15
```

What I need is to get the following.

```
    id  value col1 col2 col3
 1   1   15    X    Y    Z
 2   2   4     K    L    M
 4   3   15    M    N    B
```

I need all the row with the maximum `value` for each unique `id`, in other words. I believe answer is pretty straightforward, but could not find it. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Please notice that values could be the same for different id's, and the `value` column is in string format in my original `df`. Values it could get are finite and their hierarchy is predefined though.

Following gives "ValueError"

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['value'].idxmax()]

pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    777             if self.obj.ndim == 1:
    778                 # this can be called recursively, so need to raise ValueError
--> 779                 raise ValueError
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.groupby('id')['value'].idxmax()]` ?

Comment: It gives ValueError I was expecting that to work as well.

Comment: Btw, my original `value` column is in string type. But I have predefined hierarchy and finite values for `value` column

Comment: @Manakin write it as answer, I don't think OP is paying attention to it

Comment: @AvenDesta please see my last edit

Comment: --> 779                 raise ValueError

Comment: the suggested solution in the comment works for me for the given input

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by the value, and then drop duplicates to only keep the largest of the value you care about.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['0', '1', 10, 'W', 'A', 'B'],
['1', '1', 15, 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
['2', '2', 4, 'K', 'L', 'M'],
['3', '3', 8, 'M', 'N', 'B'],
['4', '3', 15, 'M', 'N', 'B']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['idx', 'id', 'value', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df.sort_values(by=['id','value']).drop_duplicates(subset=['id'],keep='last')
```

Comment: That's basically dropping all columns other than the largest and my raw data like 6 digit length. Would not it be inefficient?

Comment: Have you tested this and found it is inefficient? I regularly use this approach on +1m row dataframes?

Comment: @zodiac645 this should solve your problem